# Mysql Multiple Indexing Doesn't Work For A Single Query (Group By + Range Where Condition)

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have a query like below:

```
Select 
sum(r.impressions) as impressions from keyword_report r 
where r.org_id = 1
and r.report_date between '2019-09-01' and '2019-09-10'
group by r.country, r.keyword_id;
```

And I have 2 indexes on keyword_report;

```
index1: (org_id, report_date)
index2: (country, keyword_id)
```

explain format=json result:

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "138210.60"
    },
    "grouping_operation": {
      "using_temporary_table": true,
      "using_filesort": false,
      "table": {
        "table_name": "r",
        "access_type": "ref",
        "possible_keys": [
          "index1",
          "index2"
        ],
        "key": "index1",
        "used_key_parts": [
          "org_id",
          "report_date"
        ],
        "key_length": "11",
        "ref": [
          "const",
          "const"
        ],
        "rows_examined_per_scan": 125646,
        "rows_produced_per_join": 125646,
        "filtered": "100.00",
        "index_condition": "(`r`.`report_date` between '2019-09-01' and '2019-09-10')",
        "cost_info": {
          "read_cost": "125646.00",
          "eval_cost": "12564.60",
          "prefix_cost": "138210.60",
          "data_read_per_join": "162M"
        },
        "used_columns": [
          "org_id",
          "keyword_id",
          "impressions",
          "report_date",
          "country"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In table, there are approximately;

- 1000 distinct org_id,
- 500 distinct report_date,
- 30 distinct country,
- 10 millions    keyword_id.

I could not understand two things in here.

1. Why is it using temporary?
2. Why don't multiple indexes work?

As a result, how can I improve it?

Comment: "how can I improve it?" - What do you want to improve? Is it too slow for you? How many rows do match the WHERE conditions? And how many rows do you get after GROUP BY?

Answer (score 0):

The following JSON output seems to be saying that your `index1` index is being used:

```
"used_key_parts": [
  "org_id",
  "report_date"
]
```

This index can be used during the `WHERE` clause to filter off non matching records.  After this, MySQL still has to perform a `GROUP BY` aggregation, which includes a sum over the `impressions` column.  Note that an index won't really help much for the aggregation, because, by definition, the database has to touch every record, in every group, to compute the sum.  While most of the time a database will not even choose to use two different indices on the same table (but it is possible), in this case, the second `index2` index would not help much here because of the nature of your aggregation.

To give an example where you could use a single index to cover all steps of the query, consider the following:

```
SELECT
    r.country,
    MAX(r.impressions) AS max_impressions
FROM keyword_report r 
WHERE
    r.org_id = 1 AND
    r.report_date BETWEEN '2019-09-10' AND '2019-09-10'
GROUP BY
    r.country;
```

Now if you defined the following index:

```
(org_id, report_date, country, impressions)
```

Then MySQL might choose to use it.  It would work because, after filtering off records in the `WHERE` clause, it would be easy to find the max value of `impressions` for every country.

Comment: MySQL will stop at `report_date` encountering range condition *unfortunately*. So, index suggestion wont work.

Comment: report_date is range, so after report_date, your index(org_id, report_date, country, impressions) doesn't work?

Comment: @Sha I was suggesting that index for a different query, not the one you presented in your question.  For what you presented, `index1` might be as good as you can get.

Answer (score 0):

> Why don't multiple indexes work?

MySQL seldom uses more than one index at a time, unless there is possibility of `index_merge`, when using `OR` conditions etc. In this particular case, the first priority is to `WHERE` condition, that is why it uses the `index1` as it can reduce data lookups by pin-pointing to specific rows to look at by using the index. Also, logically, `WHERE` happens before `GROUP BY`, and it also helps in reducing the data to aggregate upon (instead of going through complete table).

Also, no other index suggestions would work because MySQL will stop at `report_date` encountering Range condition *unfortunately*.

> Why is it using temporary?

Because, you are using `GROUP BY` - query will first fetch all the data into a temporary table (also, your index is not covering), and once that process is done, it will perform the aggregation accordingly.

It is also explained [in MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-output.html):

> Using temporary (JSON property: using_temporary_table)
>
> To resolve the query, MySQL needs to create a temporary table to hold
>   the result. This typically happens if the query contains GROUP BY and
>   ORDER BY clauses that list columns differently.

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
select sum(r.impressions) as impressions, r.country, r.keyword_id
from keyword_report r 
where r.org_id = 1 and
      r.report_date between '2019-09-01' and '2019-09-10'
group by r.country, r.keyword_id;
```

Only one index is going to be used.  You can try an index on `keyword_report(org_id, report_date, country, keyword_id, impressions)`.  This covers the query, meaning that all columns can be used.  However, the sort will still be necessary.

In the original version of the query, you had the two operands to `BETWEEN` with the same value.  I don't think MySQL is smart enough to recognize that the two operands are the same so it is equivalent to `=`.  In this case, you should phrase the query as:

```
select sum(r.impressions) as impressions, r.country, r.keyword_id
from keyword_report r 
where r.org_id = 1 and
      r.report_date = '2019-09-10' 
group by r.country, r.keyword_id;
```

Then MySQL *might* use the index for the `GROUP BY` -- MySQL can be finicky about using indexes for `GROUP BY`.

I would be more confident of index usage for this version:

```
select ck.*,
       (select sum(impressions)
        from keyword_report r2
        where r2.country = r.country and
              r2.keyword_id = r.keyword_id and
              r2.report_date = r.report_date
       ) as total_impressions
from (select distinct country, keyword_id
      from keyword_report r 
      where r.org_id = 1 and
            r.report_date = '2019-09-10' 
     ) ck;
```

This would use the same index.

However, you cannot rephrase the query this way for an actual range.

Comment: Gordon, report_date should be range. Please check it again.